# Error in MVVM when building

Tags: mvvm, visual-studio-2012, namespaces

i just created a PCL  called Tipcalc>core, the tutorial from witch i am building it is this [one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/566270/MvvmCross-TipCalc-Step-1-Creati) . here is 
my TipViewModel.cs

```
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels;

namespace TipCalc.Core
{
public class TipViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly ICalculation _calculation;
    public TipViewModel(ICalculation calculation)
    {
        _calculation = calculation;
    }

    public override void Start()
    {
        _subTotal = 100;
        _generosity = 10;
        Recalcuate();
        base.Start();
    }

    private double _subTotal;

    public double SubTotal
    {
        get { return _subTotal; }
        set { _subTotal = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => SubTotal); Recalcuate(); }
    }

    private int _generosity;

    public int Generosity
    {
        get { return _generosity; }
        set { _generosity = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Generosity); Recalcuate(); }
    }

    private double _tip;

    public double Tip
    {
        get { return _tip; }
        set { _tip = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Tip); }
    }

    private void Recalcuate()
    {
        Tip = _calculation.TipAmount(SubTotal, Generosity);
    }
}
 }
```

The problem is that when i cuild this PCL, get the following errors:

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'ICalculation' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
TipCalc.Core
Error   2   The type or namespace name 'ICalculation' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Altough my interface and class,are right there in the Services Folder,in project.

Calculation.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TipCalc.Core.Services
{
public class Calculation : ICalculation
{
    public double TipAmount(double subTotal, int generosity)
    {
        return subTotal * ((double)generosity) / 100.0;
    }
}
 }
```

And ICalculation.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TipCalc.Core.Services
{
 public interface ICalculation
{
    double TipAmount(double subTotal, int generosity);
}
}
```

any help please?

Comment: And to add up the same sentence that never shows, "Hello to everyone!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add using in Calculation.cs

to Use ICalculation.cs

Using TipCalc.Core.Services;